# Vertical Alignment of an External Image in a Display

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, gnuplot

> [image: Wrong alignment!]

The image above was produced by `pdflatex` compiling

```
...
The left hinge is subjected to a horizontal displacement $u_A$,
\[
  u_A(t) = \Delta
  \begin{cases}
    0 & t \le 0,\\
    \displaystyle
    \frac{t}{t_1} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi\frac{t}{t_1}) & 0\le t\le
    t_1,\\
    1 & t_1 \le t.
  \end{cases} \quad \input{disp.tex}
\]
...
```

and, in turn, the image was generated by a Gnuplot script using the command `set term cairolatex pdf size 5cm,3cm` — Is it possible to achieve a better alignment of the left and right halves of the display?  Ideally an alignment on the centerlines of the two parts, but anything should be better, shouldn't it?

---

*Addendum*  Looking carefully, we have some sort of vertical alignment already, on the base line of `u_A` and the base of the *solidus* in the label of the x-axis.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You could insert an example-image if the specific graphic is not significant.

Comment: You could use `minipage`s to align formular and image.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer without an MWE, however, whatever is your graph, you can always add a proper `\coordinate` to use as `baseline`.

Main:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
The left hinge is subjected to a horizontal displacement $u_A$,
\[
  u_A(t) = \Delta
  \begin{cases}
    0 & t \le 0,\\
    \displaystyle
    \frac{t}{t_1} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi\frac{t}{t_1}) & 0\le t\le
    t_1,\\
    1 & t_1 \le t.
  \end{cases} \quad \input{disp.tex}
\]
\end{document}
```

`disp.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mybase)]
    \node[draw,rectangle, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm] (mygraph) {Your graph};
    \coordinate (mybase) at (2,-.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you name your graph you can also use `baseline=(mygraph.center)` or `baseline=(mygraph.base)`, if one of them fits what you need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I wonder if your answer does take into account the [gnuplot] tag that is present in my question...

Comment: @gboffi You can adapt it also to gnuplot. For a more detailed answer you have to give us a complete minimal example (MWE).